# Discord.js fetch older reactions

Tags: javascript, events, discord.js, partials

i have a little Problem with the discord.js `messageReactionAdd` event. So i read that this event only triggers to feteched messeages but i need to trigger this event also to older messages. So i tried it with raw events but this didnt worked out so i used partials.
But this dont work out either so can anybody help me with this?

There is like no error message or something like that. Just nothing happend

```
const { Console } = require("console")
const { Client, SystemChannelFlags, Guild, Message } = require("discord.js")
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const client = new Client({intents: ['GUILDS','DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING', 'GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS']}, { partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] })
const prefix = "!"
var fs = require('fs')

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Ready! ${client.user.tag} ist jetzt Bereit...`)
    client.user.setActivity({name: "!info - For more Information!", type: "PLAYING"})
    
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user, channel) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message:', error);
            return;
        }
    }

if(reaction.message.channel.id == channelID) {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅' ) {
            console.log(`[${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}]${user.tag}: ist nun online!`)
            const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '889124672875159582')
            const roleremove = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '889124737958170634')
            const { guild } = reaction.message
            const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id)
            member.roles.add(role)
            member.roles.remove(roleremove)
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"this dont work out either"_ is a really helpful description of your problem, thank you. Is there any error message? Is that all your code? Is `client.on('messageReactionAdd')` inside `client.once("ready")`?

Comment: Ther is no error message just nothing happend. No client.on('messageReactionAdd') isnt in client.once("ready")

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code you have?

Comment: That is the Code the only Thing i didnt send was the Client.on('message').

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I add `partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']` and react to messages even from months ago, `messageReactionAdd` fires as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the messages once the `ready` event is getting fired. You can do this by saving the id's of the messages and the id's of the channels where the messages are sent. Once the `ready` event is being fired you'll need to fetch the messages in the channels where they are sent. So for example you have saved this `json` file with the message id's and channel id's:

```json
[{
   "messageid": "1234567890",
   "channelid": "1234567890"
}, {
   "messageid": "0987654321",
   "channelid": "1234567890"
}]
```

So for example you want to fetch the messages with the id `1234567890` and `0987654321`. Then what you'll need to do is import this `json` file in your main file and go through all the data. Here is an example:

```js
const data = require('./path-to-your-json-file.json');
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client(); // Add here your intents etc.

const wait = (ms) => {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
   });
}; // A wait function to make sure that you won't get a rate-limit while fetching the messages

client.once('ready', async () => {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        const messageInfo = data[i];
        var channel = client.channels.cache.get(messageInfo.channelid);
        if(!channel) return;
        await wait(200);
        try{
           await channel.messages.fetch(messageInfo.messageid);
        } catch(error){
           console.log(`Error while fetching message with id ${messageInfo.messageid}`, error);
        }
    }
});
```

Now you've fetched all the messages and these messages should be able to detect a reaction on these messages.

Comment: So there is no way to fetch every Message in every channel?

Comment: You can maximum fetch 100 messages in a channel, so if there are a lot of messages in the channel it's hard to be able to fetch that message

Comment: How can i get the channel id and message id and put them into a json file?